# How to get JSON object by one of its values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, org.json

Trying to parse multi-level JSON in Java.

Having JSON input in format like this:

```
{"object1":["0","1", ..., "n"], 
"objects2":{
"x1":{"name":"y1","type":"z1","values":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}
"x2":{"name":"y2","type":"z2","values":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}
"x3":{"name":"y3","type":"z1","values":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}
"x4":{"name":"y4","type":"z2","values":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}
}
```

and need to get all objects from 2 by one of the attributes, e.g. get all objects with type = z1.

Using org.json*.

Tried to do something like this:

```
JSONObject GeneralSettings = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); //receiving and converting JSON;
JSONObject GeneralObjects = GeneralSettings.getJSONObject("objects2");
JSONObject p2;

JSONArray ObjectsAll = new JSONArray();

ObjectsAll = GeneralObjects.toJSONArray(GeneralObjects.names());

for (int i=0; i < GeneralObjects.length(); i++){
    p2 = ObjectsAll.getJSONObject(i);
    switch (p2.getString("type")) {
         case "z1": NewJSONArray1.put(p2); //JSON array that should contain values with type z1. 
         break;
         case "z2": NewJSONArray2.put(p2); //JSON array that should contain values with type z2. 
         default: System.out.println("error");
         break;
        }
    }
}
```

But getting null pointer exception and overall method seems not to be so well.

Please advise, is there any way to make it easier or, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your stack trace? I can't see where `NewJSONArray1` and `NewJSONArray2` are created. Also please always use a non-capitalized name for your variables (e.g. GeneralSettings -> generalSettings).

Comment: Have a look at gson library ==> https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a `NullPointerException` it's most likely that you haven't initialized `NewJSONArray1` and `NewJSONArray2`.

You didn't include their declaration, but you probably just need to do

```
NewJSONArray1=new JSONArray();
NewJSONArray2=new JSONArray();
```

before your loop.

*Aside: by convention java variables should start with a lower case letter, e.g. `newJSONArray1`*

Comment: My bad, thanks a lot! There was 2 declarations, local and global. Didn't initialize local one. Thanks a lot again! :)

Comment: Welcome. Your `ObjectsAll = new JSONArray();` is redundant by the way - you create an object and then overwrite it immediately with a new one.

Comment: Just getting section 2 objects names `ObjectsAll = GeneralObjects.toJSONArray(GeneralObjects.names());` or do you mean first initialization?

Comment: Just tried w/o it and it appears to be fine. Thanks once more :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s =
            "{\"object1\":[\"0\",\"1\",\"n\"]," +
                    "\"objects2\":{" +
                    "\"x1\":{\"name\":\"y1\",\"type\":\"z1\",\"values\":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}," +
                    "\"x2\":{\"name\":\"y2\",\"type\":\"z2\",\"values\":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}," +
                    "\"x3\":{\"name\":\"y3\",\"type\":\"z1\",\"values\":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}," +
                    "\"x4\":{\"name\":\"y4\",\"type\":\"z2\",\"values\":[19,20,21,22,23,24]}" +
                    "}}";
    System.out.println(s);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject object2 = json.optJSONObject("objects2");
    if (object2 == null) {
        return;
    }

    JSONArray result = new JSONArray();

    for (Object key : object2.keySet()) {
        JSONObject object = object2.getJSONObject(key.toString());

        String type = object.optString("type");
        if ("z1".equals(type)) {
            System.out.println(object.toString());
            result.put(object);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always convert it to string and use json-path:
https://code.google.com/p/json-path/